# mysql list of columns check only one of those have value

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have a list of columns like a, b, c, d, e, f. 
Ideally only one of those can have value. 
How can I find out the rows that break this rule. 
thanks.

Comment: Rest of them will have `null` value or empty value ?

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I would be very attentive to such schema. Something wrong with your DB design. Normalize your table. And probably you will have less questions like this one.

Comment: sad it's a legacy one, so I am just trying to make things work for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that no value in a column means `null` (not empty string `''`). We can utilize comparison operators `IS NOT NULL`. It returns 1 if the value is not `null`; else 1.

Sum of the above-mentioned comparison results for each of the columns should be equal to 1 only (if there is only one non-null column in a row).

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name 
WHERE ((a IS NOT NULL) + 
       (b IS NOT NULL) + 
       (c IS NOT NULL) +
       (d IS NOT NULL) + 
       (e IS NOT NULL) +
       (f IS NOT NULL)) <> 1
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/opbpWWGioCxCdPkwrqKjFr/0)

Comment: It's the same idea as Lukasz has. Thanks.

Comment: @Sandy String operations are less efficient. This approach is more efficient; and you will realize the difference when there is lot of data.

Comment: Thanks for the info, It's indeed increase the time from 9.6 to 9.5. I just have a terrible structure over here. Thank you Madhur.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE LENGTH(CONCAT(
      IF(a IS NULL,'','.'),
      IF(b IS NULL,'','.'),
      IF(c IS NULL,'','.'),
      IF(d IS NULL,'','.'),
      IF(e IS NULL,'','.'),
      IF(f IS NULL,'','.'))) <> 1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4ee56055e33695099db1a9c4b354f25)**

Comment: I think Madhur answer is more performant. We don't need to apply extra functions: `LENGTH` and `CONCAT`. `+` against boolean or integer should be faster I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's working, just I have 11 columns to match, so it takes a long time. It is a nice work around.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should not have 6 columns for one value, but instead, 1 column, perhaps plus a second column to say which thing it represents (a..f).